# Fazer botão <a> alterar href=" " a cada novo acesso em determinada página

Tags: php

Estou com uma pequena dúvida em um projeto no qual estou desenvolvendo.

Acontece o seguinte, tenho 2 botões na página, como estes ( **idênticos em posições diferentes** ):

Topo da página:

`<a target="_blank" class="btn-primary" href="http://localhost/exemplo/"> Clique Aqui </a>`

Final da página:

`<a target="_blank" class="btn-primary" href="http://localhost/exemplo/"> Clique Aqui </a>`

Preciso fazer com que cada vez que a página que contém esses botões for acessada, aumente o número na pasta. Exemplo:

A uma pessoa acessou essa página a primeira vez: ( Observe que no link contém **/01/** )

`http://localhost/exemplo/01/`

Quando uma **outra** pessoa acessa pela segunda vez: ( Observe que no link contém **/02/** )

`http://localhost/exemplo/02/`

E assim consecutivamente: (**/03/**, **/04/**, **/05/**, **/06/**, etc...)

Cada novo acesso aumente o valor no link, de forma crescente.

Além disso, é possível implementar algo que possa me dizer em qual número está no momento? Não tenho nenhuma ideia, **talvez algo como um arquivo que seja atualizado (txt talvez)**, me informando em qual número parou.

Comment: Posso te mostrar um jeito de fazer, é simples. Mas se possível, explique a razão disso. Para mim não parece algo bom. Antes de julgar ou até mesmo postar uma resposta, gostaria de entender o motivo.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta pra não haver desentendimentos.

Comment: Não entendi a correlação disso com esses números. Ficou mais confuso.

Comment: VOcê é do Maranhão?

Comment: Sou sim amigo @Sampaio Leal

Comment: Desculpe @Daniel Omine mas não era essa "resposta" que esperava de você. Espero que outros usuários possam responder essa pergunta.

Comment: Vou tentar editar essa pergunta de uma forma mais "comunitária" como diz.

Comment: Agora vamos deixar a pergunta mais limpa, apagando esses comentários. :)

Comment: sua ideia é saber quantas pessoas acessaram a página?

Comment: Isso seria apenas um complemento amigo @André Baill, o principal é que a cada acesso, aumente aquele numerozinho depois da pasta "/exemplo/" a cada novo acesso.  :) Acontece que eu gostaria de saber em qual número parou, porque assim eu não precisaria acessar a página, e ser +1 desses que acessaram.

Comment: Faz um arquivo e grava no txt, ai cada vez, recupera o que tem +1

Comment: Editei meu comentário :) Você poderia fazer uma resposta?

Comment: Você utiliza algum framework de desenvolvimento ou `php` puro?

Comment: Uso PHP puro amigo @Kenny Rafael :D

Comment: Nesse caso dá mais trabalho...rsrsrs

Comment: Você vai ter que criar um rota no .htaccess e salvar um `JSON` com a contagem pra ir atualizando sempre, não consigo desenvolver algum código agora pra ajudar, mas o caminho é esse...

Comment: Vejo algo tão simples. Faz de contas que é uma página HTML na qual tem esse botão que tem um link que precisa ser alterado a cada novo acesso, como coloquei na pergunta :)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46634/discussion-on-question-by-alexandre-lopes-php-fazer-botao-a-alterar-href)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar simplesmente o `.htaccess` para que sempre que for clicado o link, a página passe o valor para o PHP:

```
RewriteRule ^exemplo/([0-9]*)/$ index.php?contador=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Depois no `index.php` basta aumentar esse contador em 1 e imprimir o link:

```
$contador = $_GET['contador'] + 1;
echo "<a target='_blank' class='btn-primary' href='http://localhost/exemplo/".$contador."/'> Clique Aqui </a>";
```

---

Ou pode usar o ler do ficheiro se for ao carregar a página:

```
$file = 'exemplo.txt'; 

$atual = file_get_contents($file); 

$contador = $atual + 1 ;

echo "<a target='_blank' class='btn-primary' href='http://localhost/exemplo/".$contador."/'> Clique Aqui </a>";
```

Por fim, para gravar num ficheiro pode usar a função [`file_put_contents($file, $string);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), por exemplo:

```
$file     = 'exemplo.txt'; 
file_put_contents($file, $contador);
```

***Nota: Tenha em atenção para o que vai usar isso, pode ser que esteja a usar de forma errada.***

Comment: Jorge, é possível fazer com que ao invés do script adicionar +1 a cada vez que é recarregado, adicione +1 a cada novo ip (a cada novo visitante), invés de ser a cada recarregamento ?

Comment: @AlexandreLopes  há sim, mas isso já dava outra pergunta. Precisavas de guardar os IP's e confirmar sempre que carregasses a página ou fizesses um login se for o caso, e só depois atualizavas o count. Mas como te digo, isso dá uma pergunta nova. Se quiseres fazer uma nova pergunta...

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta ao comentário meu amigo Jorge! :D - Vou fazer uma nova pergunta :D

Comment: Jorge, aqui está a pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167270/fazer-bot%c3%a3o-a-alterar-href-a-cada-novo-visitante-ip-em-determinada-p%c3%a1g

Comment: @AlexandreLopes ainda não tive tempo, quando puder respondo.