# Fazer botão <a> alterar href=“ ” a cada novo visitante ( IP ) em determinada página

Tags: php

Estou com uma pequena dúvida em um projeto no qual estou desenvolvendo.

Acontece o seguinte, tenho 2 botões na página, como estes ( idênticos em posições diferentes ):

Topo da página:

```
<a target="_blank" class="btn-primary" href="http://localhost/exemplo/"> Clique Aqui </a>
```

Final da página:

```
<a target="_blank" class="btn-primary" href="http://localhost/exemplo/"> Clique Aqui </a>
```

> Preciso fazer com que cada vez que a página que contém esses botões for acessada por um novo visitante, aumente o número na pasta. Exemplo:

Se uma pessoa acessou essa página a primeira vez: ( Observe que no link contém **/01/** )

`http://localhost/exemplo/01/`

Quando uma **outra** pessoa acessa pela segunda vez: ( Observe que no link contém **/02/** )

`http://localhost/exemplo/02/`

E assim consecutivamente: (**/03/**, **/04/**, **/05/**, **/06/**, etc...)

> A cada novo visitante nessa página, ou seja, **(a cada novo IP)** aumente o valor no link, de forma crescente.

Comment: relacionado → http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157907/4793

Comment: Vou olhar Dani :)

Comment: Daniel, sim, aquele é um outro exemplo (adiciona +1 a cada recarregamento "F5"), nesse exemplo, quero que adicione apenas a cada novo visitante "IP".

Comment: Você já tem a lógica que resolveu a questão antiga. Use aquela mesma lógica e adapte-a para essa nova regra de negócio (o esquema com o IP).

Comment: Pra que você precisa exatamente dos IPs diferentes? Outro método para detectar se aquele usuário já esteve no site não é suficiente?

Comment: Concordo com o @DanielOmine a pergunta é praticamente idêntica, bastava adaptar a lógica checando apenas o IP, ou seja pode trocar o `$file = 'exemplo.txt';` por `$file = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'.txt';`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Claramente é duplicata. Mas como aquela é de outra pessoa, não dá pra usar os comentários pra detalhar o serviço.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Mas se fizer esta troca, não vai dar certo, pois vai ser adicionado +1 a cada recarregamento no arquivo, fazendo com que todos os visitantes comecem com "http://localhost/exemplo/01/" e se atualizarem, vão adicionando +1, e a questão é só adicionar +1 para cada visitante, se não for um novo visitante, o número que é gravado nesse arquivo TXT continua igual.

Comment: O `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` que o @GuilhermeNascimento disse é justamente para resolver isso que vc acaba de dizer. Ele separa por IP se usar como no exemplo dado.

Comment: Sim @Bacco ele grava um arquivo .TXT renomeado com o IP do visitante, mas o que acontece... Como falei antes, no caso se eu acessar a primeira vez, vai ficar "1", se acessar pela segunda "2", e assim consecutivamente para todos, ou seja, todos vão começar com "1", e o certo é começar de onde parou. O certo seria verificar se existe um arquivo .TXT criado com o número do IP, se não tiver, ele vai adicionar +1 em outro arquivo .TXT, no caso esse `$file = 'exemplo.txt';`.

Comment: Isso que não sei como fazer :(

Comment: é o meso exemplo da resposta do @Jorgeb. lá na outra pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/158024/3635 só trocar o `$file = 'exemplo.txt';` pelo IP do visitante, e vai continuar de onde parou, isto tanto no file_get_contents quanto no file_put_contents

Comment: Eu fiz o que você disse, acontece que ele cria um novo arquivo com o número do IP, só que esse arquivo ex: (123.432.445.43.txt) sempre começa com "1". Ou seja, qualquer visitante vai começar com `http://localhost/exemplo/01/`, e se recarregar vai aumentado o número, e o que quero é justamente evitar que seja aumentado sem necessidade, apenas comece de onde parou, e caso não exista um arquivo .txt com o IP do vistante, fosse adicionado +1 para outro arquivo `exemplo.txt`.

Comment: Acho que vou ter que criar uma pergunta sobre isso.

Comment: De acordo com essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/158024/61633) é só você usar o `.htaccess`, para passar o link.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes já resolveste o assunto?

Comment: Sim @JorgeB. :D [Aqui.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167993/php-criar-arquivo-txt-com-log-de-ips-dos-visitantes)

Comment: Parece que ficou resolvido na pergunta duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167993/php-criar-arquivo-txt-com-log-de-ips-dos-visitantes

Answer (score 5):

Eu gravaria cada IP no banco fazendo a condição de adicionar apenas se ele não for já cadastrado.

A função `<? echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];?>` pega o IP.

Se esse IP não constar já no banco é um novo. Assim o número de registros no banco é o número de visitantes diferentes.

Comment: Gabriel, você poderia fazer um exemplo? Sou novo com PHP :/

Answer (score 2):

AO meu ver, você vai precisar capturar todos os acessos individualmentes para sempre somar +1 nesse link de acordo com o número da visita.
Você pode fazer isso talvez salvando em um banco de dados bem leve o número do acesso (Você pode gravar o IP do visitante para saber que é um visitante diferente).

Ou gravar em um arquivo fisico no servidor.

Comment: Mario, você poderia fazer um exemplo? Sou novo com PHP :/

Comment: De preferência esse exemplo que grava em um arquivo físico, no caso seria um txt correto? :D

Answer (score 1):

Eu ia apenas editar a resposta do @Gabriel Gomes mas acabou ficando maior do que eu esperava.

> Eu gravaria cada IP no banco fazendo a condição de adicionar apenas se
>   ele não for já cadastrado.
>
> A função  pega o IP.
>
> Se esse IP não constar já no banco é um novo. Assim o número de
>   registros no banco é o número de visitantes diferentes.

No arquivo .php:

```
$visitante = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
function verificarVisitasDoIP($visitante){
  if(jaExisteNoBanco($visitante)){
    return --código para pegar o numero de visitas desse IP--;
    }
    else{
      --código para salvar o $visitante em um novo registro. Faça o valor inicial ou DEFAULT ser 1 para dar certo.--;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

No arquivo .js (usando jQuery):

```
$.post("arquivo.php, function(data,status){
  if(status == "success"){
    $(".btn-primary").attr("href", "http:\//localhost/exemplo/"+data);
  }
});
```

[Explicação sobre o $.load() neste link.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)

Com isso, acredito que você consegue alterar.

Comment: Me complicou nesses "--código para" Kkkkk, como seria isso?

Comment: Você precisa guardar essas informações em um banco de dados. O "código para" seria uma conexão com o banco salvando e trazendo essas informações. Você deve guardar no mínimo os IPs dos visitantes e fazer um contador de visitas. Ao verificar a visita, você procura no banco se o IP já foi gravado. Se não foi, você grava o novo IP e acrescenta mais uma visita ao contador. Se o IP já existe nos registros, você deixa o contador como está.

Comment: Não sei como fazer isso :'(

Comment: Mas tem um porém, "Se o IP já existe nos registros, você deixa o contador como está.", e se outra pessoa visitar, vai aumentar +1, então esse primeiro visitante também vai receber +1 se ele recarregar a página ?

Comment: Cada vez que a página carrega, a função confere a visita. Na primeira vez o registro não estará lá. Com um F5, o registro já conta. Sobre não saber banco de dados, é outra questão. Você precisaria implementar ou ter alguém que faça por você.

Comment: Vou testar amigo :)

Comment: @CleitonOliveira não sei se entendi errado, mas ao postar uma resposta diferente, você fez o correto, pois não é permitido editar respostas que você não é o autor e adicionar informações que o autor não tenha colocado. Isso é apenas uma dica :)

Answer (score 1):

**Recomendo fortemente que você siga os conselhos dos comentarios acima e use um banco de dados**, mas só pela ciencia você pode usar o scandir (http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) para pegar a ultima pasta criada.

```
php > var_dump(scandir('./', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING));

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "03"

  [1]=>
  string(2) "02"

  [2]=>
  string(2) "01"

  [3]=>
  string(2) ".."

  [4]=>
  string(1) "."
}
```

Depois pegar o primeiro index do vetor (Perceba o argumento de ordenação informado):

```
$newFolderId = ((int) $scan[0]) + 1;
```

E finalizar criando uma nova pasta com o id obtido. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

```
mkdir('./' . $newFolderId, 0700);
```

Pronto, você pode aproveitar a variavel usada para a criação da pasta para imprimir o link para a mesma.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, fiz a lógica pra você, agora só implementar ai e criar o banco de dados, fiz utilizando mysql.

```
<?php
//Função que pega IP
function pegaIP(){
    $http_client_ip       = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $http_x_forwarded_for = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote_addr          = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    // Verifica se o IP existe na internet
    if(!empty($http_client_ip)){

        $ip = $http_client_ip;

    } elseif(!empty($http_x_forwarded_for)){// Verifica se o acesso veio de um proxy

        $ip = $http_x_forwarded_for;

    } else {//Caso não encontre das outras maneiras, pega do jeito tradicional

        $ip = $remote_addr;

    }
    return $ip;
}

//Conexão com o banco
$servidor = '';
$banco = '';
$usuario = '';
$senha = '';
$link = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
$db = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

if(!$link){
    echo "Erro ao conectar com o bando de dados!<br/>";
    echo mysql_error();
}

$IP = pegaIP();

//Query para pesquisar no banco se essa pessoa ja entrou
$querySelect = "SELECT * FROM minhaTabela WHERE ip = ".$IP;
//Executa a query
$resultSelect = mysql_query($querySelect);

//Verifica se houve erros na query
if($resultSelect){

    //Verifica se o IP ja acessou o banco (se retornar 0 não acessou porque não existe registro desse IP)
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultSelect) == 0){

        //Query para inserir o ip na tabela
        $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO minhaTabela ('ip') VALUES ('".$IP."')";
        //Executa a query
        $resultInsert = mysql_query($queryInsert);
        //Verifica se houve erros na query
        if($resultInsert){
            //Pega o id do ultimo registro inserido
            $numero = mysql_insert_id();
        }else{
            echo mysql_error();
        }

    }else{
        //Pega os dados da consulta
        $coluna = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSelect);

        //Adciona o id da pessoa na variavel numero
        $numero = $coluna['id'];

    }

}else{
    echo mysql_error();
}

//gera o link com o ID da pessoa
echo '<a href="http://localhost/exemplo/'.$numero.'/">Link</a>';
```