# PHP - Criar arquivo .TXT com log de IP's dos Visitantes

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte link:

```
<a target='_blank' class='btn-primary' href='exemplo/1/'> Clique Aqui </a>
```

Preciso que cada vez que a página que contém esse link for acessada por um visitante diferente ( **IP** ), seja alterado o número no link.

> Penso que seria interessante que fosse criado um arquivo `.txt` contendo os números de cada IP e o número que cada IP ficará responsável.

Exemplo ( **numeros.txt** ):

```
123.456.789.00 - 1
321.543.765.99 - 2
543.210.456.22 - 3
435.647.533.33 - 4
```

E assim consecutivamente...

> Preciso que seja verificado se o IP do visitante já está nessa lista, se estiver ele pega o número que é responsável por este IP e coloca no link, se não estiver, então é adicionado o novo IP na lista e agregado o número que ele ficará responsável e então colocado no link, ficando assim:

**Exemplo:** O Visitante tem um IP `321.543.765.99` que ficou responsável pelo número `2`.

Então será exibido:

```
<a target='_blank' class='btn-primary' href='exemplo/2/'> Clique Aqui </a>
```

> É possível fazer isto? Como?

Comment: original: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157907/fazer-bot%C3%A3o-a-alterar-href-a-cada-novo-acesso-em-determinada-p%C3%A1gina e relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167270/fazer-bot%c3%a3o-a-alterar-href-a-cada-novo-visitante-ip-em-determinada-p%c3%a1g

Comment: Daniel, a questão aqui é outra amigo, entenda por favor. Está pergunta está totalmente diferente.

Comment: Sim.. pois não disse ser duplicada, mas relacionada. Para outros entenderem o contexto por trás disso. Note também que não fui eu quem fechou a outra questão.

Comment: Ah sim, muito obrigado Daniel por compreender! :D Vlw msm

Comment: por isso a importância em mostrar as originais.. Quem pega o bonde andando vai interpretar de forma dispersa.

Comment: Como ficou demonstrado nos comentários da resposta que as dúvidas são as mesmas das duas duplicatas anteriores, fechei para evitar o excesso de informação repetida espalhada no site. Sugiro não abrir perguntas com outras em andamento, a não ser que os assuntos sejam de fato diferentes (não apenas versões diferentes do texto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um escopo de como poderá implementar:

O arquivo txt para testes está assim

```
123.456.789.00 - 1
321.543.765.99 - 2
543.210.456.22 - 3
435.647.533.33 - 4
```

Essa é a rotina:

```
<?php

$ip = '123.123.123.123';
$file = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'tmp6.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($file);

$number = null;
$ip_len = strlen($ip) + 3;
$pos = strpos($content, $ip);

if ($pos !== false) {
    $part1 = substr($content, $pos + $ip_len);
    //echo $part1.'<br> len '.strlen($part1);
    //var_dump(strpos($part1, PHP_EOL));
    $number = substr($part1, 0, strpos($part1, PHP_EOL));
} else {
    $pos = strrpos($content, ' ');
    //var_dump($pos);
    $number = trim(substr($content, $pos)) + 1;
    $fs = fopen($file, 'a');
    fwrite($fs, $ip.' - '.$number.PHP_EOL);
    fclose($fs);
}

echo 'number '.$number;
```

Esteja ciente de que é possível otimizar e, o script acima possui inconsistência em relação a possíveis falhas.

O script confia no valor de `PHP_EOL` como caracter de quebra de linha. Em determinados ambientes ou situações pode ser incompatível. Exemplo o txt pode ser salvo com quebras de linha variadas. Para minimizar esse problema, certifique-se que sempre salvará com um mesmo padrão de formatação.

Ainda assim, considere o uso de SQLite ou outra lógica para simplificar esse problema que poderia nem mesmo existir.

Uma sugestão é apenas codificar o IP e usar essa string codificada no lugar do número para formar a URL. Nesse caso não precisa fazer nada dessa tranqueira com txt, sqlite, nada mesmo. Uma única linha já resolveria

```
echo md5($ip);
```

É assim que eu resolveria o problema, para evitar ter que dar toda essa volta que parece desnecessária. Por fim, a decisão é de cada um.

Comment: Parece ser muito bom! :3 Vou testar agora!

Comment: Exatamente Daniel, cada IP ficará responsável por um número, no caso quando eu fizer o primeiro acesso com meu IP, eu ficarei com o número 1, caso outra pessoa acesse ela ficará responsável pelo número 2, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Hummm, então Daniel, esses IP's não sou eu quem vai criar manualmente, será criado pelo próprio servidor, e cada vez que acessado por um novo IP, será editado automaticamente esse arquivo TXT, inserindo esse novo IP e seu número, no caso um "+1" rsrs.

Comment: Acabei de abrir o arquivo .TXT que foi criado, e está em branco!

Comment: é porque file_put_contents sobrescreve... use uma função que escreve no fim do arquivo, como fwrite(), ou use FILE_APPEND

Comment: fiz upgrade, agora adiciona o ip caso não exista no txt

Comment: é, mas agora está acrescentando o número ao IP ao invés de fixá-lo...

Comment: Então Daniel, agora está exibindo como você planejou: `IP: 77.543.765.930, Número: 1`. Acontece que quando eu recarrego a página, ele soma +1, ficando `IP: 77.543.765.930, Número: 2` e assim em diante. Ele deve ficar travado no número no qual ficou responsável.

Comment: Exatamente @ShutUpMagda Você está testando também :D

Comment: Só olhei a lógica @alexandre-lopes... Tem uma operação de soma ali...

Comment: aí agora vc está direcionando a questão para a  original o que tornaria essa aqui uma duplicata.  .. O script faz o que a pergunta pede e nada mais. O restante é contigo. Se tem alguma outra regra,  sou alheio a isso

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, nova versão.. teste aí.. não vou editar mais.

Comment: PERFEITO!!! Era exatamente isso Daniel, você conseguiu resolver a questão! :D Muito obrigado por tudo, vai desculpando aí por qualquer coisa, é que sou novo com `PHP` aí não consegui resolver sozinho. :/ De qualquer forma, muito obrigado. Parabéns pelo seu conhecimento! :P